# How to view previous screen in current viewcontroller background in iphone?

Tags: iphone

im new to iphone, i have two view controllers one is homepage and other is Flipscreen and its work in good, but i want when i navigate flipscreen, the background is just like a mirror?
how? please any one help me..

I tried the code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like a mirror in the sense? If you need a clear back ground, try `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`. Try to post your questions clear.